# Extract algorithm from number distribution

Tags: numbers, artificial-intelligence, design-patterns

I was wondering if there are neural networks or genetic algorithms which could approximate a random number generation sequence?

```
Example - Input:
5 5 6 6 1 1 3 3 6 1 1 1 3 2 3 5 1 1 4 5 8 9 8 9 3 1 4 3 1 3 5 5 4 9 9 4 9 4 6 1 3 1 

Simulation - Output:
5 5 8 6 1 5 3 3 1 1 1 5 3 2 1 5 1 1 3 5 8 0 8 9 3 1 4 2 1 3 5 5 4 9 5 4 9 4 2 1 3 1
```

Comment: What are your criteria for approximation?  If the input sequence is completely random (which is difficult to attain in practice), then the output sequence wouldn't be able to predict it at all.

Comment: Ok lets say the input sequence is not random but I don't know how the sequence is generated. Is there a way to find this out?

Comment: Okay.  I just wanted to clarify what you meant.  See my answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [Time Series Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series).

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure but maybe there are correlations between number sequences.

Comment: @user366121 Yes.  There's something called an autoregressive moving average (ARMA) model that will gradually fit a model to the data.  TSA is a huge field, but probably a bit off topic for this site.  Poke around over on http://stats.stackexchange.com (it's part of the same group of sites as SO) to see what's out there.

Answer (score -1):

I would say no:

- neural networks need to be trained on input patterns, and then you can essentially use them for classifying/clustering new inputs, or for approximating functions
- genetic algorithms actually require randomness to mutate individuals